# Firebase Data Structure - Am I on the right track?

Tags: firebase

I first heard of Firebase yesterday.  Looks very promising to me.
I have ready several articles on de-normalizing your data in Firebase.  I'm thinking about migrating from a MySQL backend to Firebase.  This will be used in a iOS app.

The typical scenario:

- A hurricane develops
- The hurricane center issues advisories every 6 hours for the storm
- Each advisory contains future positions (forecast)..up to 8 total positions
- Each position has a location (lat/long), strength of storm (wind speed)
- Each position also has wind radius information associated with that position

**Specific Question**:  In my structure below, should I have positions nested under advisories?
Any other tips/recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my first stab at the data structure:

```
{
storms: {
    id: "AL012015"
    name: "Alex"
    basin: "NWP"
}
advisories: {
    stormID: "AL012015"
    advisorynumber: "1"     //will have many advisories throughout the lifecycle of the storm
    date: "2015-06021 18:00:00"
    cat: "H1"
    eyediameter: "20"
    movedirection: "270"
    movespeed: "13"
    pressure: "999"
    fa: "full text advisory"
    pa: "full test public advisory"
    cd: "full text cyclone discussion"
    agency: "NHC"
}
positions: {            //can be up to 8 positions per advisory
    stormid: "AL012015"
    advisorynumber: "1"
    positions: {    
        position1: {
            datetime: "2015-07-21 18:00:00"
            speed: "75"
            lat: "23.5"
            lon: "-78.2"
            radius34ne: "120"  //radius of the 34 knot winds speeds from center
            radius34se: "145"
            radius34sw: "100"
            radius34nw: "120"
            radius50ne: "90"  //radius of the 50 knot winds speeds from center
            radius50se: "100"
            radius50sw: "75"
            radius50nw: "90"
            radius64ne: "60"  //radius of the 64 knot winds speeds from center
            radius64se: "75"
            radius64sw: "50"
            radius64nw: "60"
        }
        position2: {
            datetime: "2015-07-22 00:00:00"
            speed: "85"
            lat: "24.5"
            lon: "-75.2"
            radius34ne: "120"  //radius of the 34 knot winds speeds from center
            radius34se: "145"
            radius34sw: "100"
            radius34nw: "120"
            radius50ne: "90"  //radius of the 50 knot winds speeds from center
            radius50se: "100"
            radius50sw: "75"
            radius50nw: "90"
            radius64ne: "60"  //radius of the 64 knot winds speeds from center
            radius64se: "75"
            radius64sw: "50"
            radius64nw: "60"
        }
        position3: {
            datetime: "2015-07-22 06:00:00"
            speed: "60"
            lat: "26.5"
            lon: "-72.2"
            radius34ne: "50"  //radius of the 34 knot winds speeds from center
            radius34se: "55"
            radius34sw: "50"
            radius34nw: "45"
            radius50ne: "20"  //radius of the 50 knot winds speeds from center
            radius50se: "20"
            radius50sw: "20"
            radius50nw: "20"
            //no 64 knot wind radius because "speed" < 64
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julian's answer is correct and I wanted to add a few things and provide an example.

With the below, we have three main parent nodes, storms, advisories and positions.

The parent nodes in each is a Firebase auto-generated id. It's good to disassociate child data nodes from the parent node names.

In the storms, advisories and positions nodes, each child has a name generated by autoId as well ( push() ). In the advisories and positions node, there is a child that refers back to the storms nodes.

```
storms:
  storm_id_0:
    id: "AL012015"
    name: "Alex"
    basin: "NWP"
  storm_id_1:
    id: "BI01923"
    name: "Biff"
    basin: "NWP"

advisories:
   advisory_id_0:
     stormID: storm_id_0
     advisorynumber: "1"
     date: "2015-10021 18:00:00"
     eyediameter: "20"
     text: "The eye wall is building"
   advisory_id_1:
     stormID: storm_id_0
     advisorynumber: "2"
     date: "2015-10021 18:00:00"
     eyediameter: "25"
     text: "The storm has deep convection"

positions:
  position_id_0
    stormID: storm_id_0
    datetime: "2015-07-21 18:00:00"
    speed: "75"
    lat: "23.5"
    lon: "-78.2"
    radius34ne: "120"
  position_id_1
    stormID: storm_id_0
    datetime: "2015-07-21 18:00:00"
    speed: "75"
    lat: "23.5"
    lon: "-78.2"
    radius34ne: "120"
  position_id_2
    stormid: storm_id_0
    datetime: "2015-07-21 18:00:00"
    speed: "75"
    lat: "23.5"
    lon: "-78.2"
    radius34ne: "120"
```

There are some interesting things that you can query on.

For example: you can query (or and observe event) for all of the advisories for storm_id_0, storm_id_1 etc. Not very exciting but gets you the base data for each storm.

You can query for all storms that have crossed latitude 23.5. Much more exciting

Even query for all storms that have an eye diameter between 20 and 25. Very exciting.

If the data is nested too deep, you can still get at that same info, but it requires a lot more work on the client side.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase prefers flattened data structures, so don't nest positions under advisories.

Also, if you plan to keep records of each storm, you may want to nest each storm's properties like "id" and "basin" under the storm's "name" (or you can use ID if the name could have duplicates). Same would go for each advisories and positions.

Firebase's website also has a great guide for best-practice data structures to use with their backend service: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  That makes perfect since... keep it flat.